# Multiple Chart Series in chart control

Tags: c#, java, javascript, asp.net, sql-server-2005

I am a novice programmer using ms chart control for my dashboard, I have a problem displaying chart series.

Here is my sample query & result

Sample Query: "SELECT Brand, sales, Manufacturer From TABLE"

```
Sample Result:
         BRAND       SALES   MANUFACTURER
 Row 1   BrandA       10000     MfgA
 Row 2   BrandY       7000      MfgY
 Row 3   BrandZ       12000     MfgZ
```

How can I display BrandA for XValueMember & Salesvalue(10000) for YValueMembers as Series1 having a column chart type.

And to display BrandY & BrandZ for XValueMember ; Salesvalue for YValueMembers as Series2 
having a line chart  type.

I want my chart to have 2 Y-axis; Series1 for primary Y-axis & series2 for secondary Y-axis.

My problem here is how can I display BrandA in Series1 and BrandY,BrandZ in Series2 where the values are in the same field?

Or is it possible to set more than one data source for the chart control?

I've been working on this for two days but I wasn't able to get the desired result.

I hope somebody could help me.

Answer (score 1):

Dont know how to achieve that with MSChart.

In this project, has a sample of a "column combination chart" where you are able to display one brand as a column(primary) e the other as a line(secundary).

http://liberofusioncharts.codeplex.com/

[image]

Download it and take a look at Column Combination Chart sample available for ASP.Net Webforms.

Comment: Hi Roberto,


Thank you for your response.

My web application is written in vs2008 using C#, I will try to download a trial version of vs2010 to view your sample application.


Thanks & Regards
-GCA

Comment: It's been developed in vs2010 but does not use any resource of c#4 or .Net4, then it'll be easy to get converted to vs2008. regards

Comment: Hi Roberto, I got an error while running your sample application in vs2008. "Unrecognized attribute 'controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion'". I expectthe convertion wizard to appear while opening the application but it does not in vs2008. I also tried to change the web config manaully, but the error still occur.

Comment: Hi, I've just upload a solution converted to VS 2008 and .Net 3.5. It has only a project sample for Asp.Net Webforms and doesn't have the sample version for MVC. You can download it at: http://liberofusioncharts.codeplex.com/releases/view/59103

Comment: Hi Roberto, thank you so much for your help I already solve my problem.